# When to use html controls and server control in ASP.NET ..?

Tags: asp.net

In our project,some web pages uses both html and server-side controls.Handlers for the HTML controls are some javascript functions,but they perform server side operation same as server side controls do.
Then why use html controls to perform server side function when it can be done using server side controls..?
Please suggest as I am new to web designing using ASP.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a .net developer there really isn't any benefit to using standard html controls server-side.  You can always set them to run at server, but you do lose some of the functionality that comes with server controls.  Sometimes you'll see a lot of html elements with `runat` set.  In my experience you'll see this a lot with .net projects that were ported over from asp classic.

You might also see this when .net developers work with graphic designers or front end developers who don't really understand .net.  They'll just use html elements and let the developer worry about the back end.

With unobtrusive css and javascript you really don't need to use html elements in your markup.  There is almost always a server control that will do the same but wit more backend functionality.

Comment: Using server-side controls without any thought is an another extreme... The fact you can use them doesn't mean you should do it every single time. The developer should carefully decide and not just mindlessly spray them all over the place, because he's `a .net developer`...

Comment: This is a question about using html controls and accessing them server side.

Comment: Really? `When to use html controls and server control in ASP.NET ..?`

Comment: I was answering the question.  Not the title.  It helps if you read the entire question. `Handlers for the HTML controls are some javascript functions,but they perform server side operation`

Comment: Also `why use html controls to perform server side function`  My answere detailed just a couple of scenarios where html elements are being run on the server.

Comment: `WHEN to use html controls and when a server control.` I agree with you here. But that wasn't the question.  The question was very clear. `Then why use html controls to perform server side function when it can be done using server side controls..?`  This is what I was answering.  I'm not saying you're wrong.  I'm just answering the question that was asked.  I'm not even sure why you're so upset.  Anyway, the OP should have an answer to his question between our two posts.  I answered the question directly, and you gave additional helpful info.  There is no need to insult people here.

Comment: I added an edit to my answer to cover any misunderstanding people may have.  It seems to be what threw you off, I assumed the context was easily understood. I stand corrected.